# rails postgresql query regex length limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am making a rails app and I need to use long regular expressions in my queries. I found that in the Postgrssql is a 32 kilobyte limit on regular expression length. 
Here is how my query looks like, regex that I am using is around 1 million characters long

```
MyModel.where('model_field ~* ?', 'some very very long regex')
```

But this query raises an error `REG_ETOOBIG`.
How to increse regex length limit in the postgress or how to deal with the queries with very long regexes?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regex? A regex of that size would take a very very long time to evaluate.

Comment: Time is not an issue in this case, search by regex will be running in the background

Comment: It would also require an immense amount of memory. Anyways, the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html recommends you to write your own perl-function.